# Can this question be asked here or it's too broad? (or too simple, or whatever)

Tags: discussion

Since I ignore a lot of technical details, I wonder if this question can be asked here or if it's too broad, too simple, unanswerable or whatever and therefore candidate for being closed.

I want to ask if it's possible to use the technology being developed for going to Mars, to go to Vesta or Pallas and set up a base there, since in their closest orbit points to Mars, they should be about the same distance the Earth is to Mars ,and since transportation is one of the main challenges for setting a base in Mars. (besides other such as food supply, water supply, oxigen supply, energy supply, radiation protection, temperature protection, etc.)

Comment: To clarify, you want to ask if it is possible to piggy-back off of Mars to launch missions from *there* to Vesta or Pallas?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible with the technology already developed for going to Mars and setting up a base in Mars, to set up a base in Vesta or Pallas. May be it isnt possible because Mars have better conditions for setting up a base such as water, an atmosphere, warmer temperatures, etc.  And  yes, launching missions from Mars to Vesta or Pallas.

Comment: To be clear, the technology for setting up a base on Mars has not been developed, not entirely. Is it technologically possible? I would argue yes, but that is different from already being developed.

Comment: I worry your question would be too speculative here. Perhaps a better fit for Worldbuilding.

Comment: @called2voyage I thought World Building as an alternative too. Thanks